# R: Avoid loop or row apply function

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, data.table

I've following two data frame 
**df_sales** and **df_supply**.

I want to merge the sale to supply in such a manner that my df_sales table have  DATE_SUPPLY and QNT_SUPPLY from df_supply on below conditions

***Condition**: DATE_SUPPLY should be recent DATE_SUPPLY of corresponding "ITEM" for corresponding "STORE", i.e, `DATE_SALE <- max(df_supply[df_supply$DATE_SUPPLY <= df_sales$DATE_SALE & df_supply$STORE == df_sales$STORE & df_supply$ITEM == df_sales$ITEM,]$DATE_SUPPLY)*`

It can be possible using row apply function or simply by writing loop. But I have huge dataset so don't want looping.

```
df_sales <- data.frame("STORE"=c(1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002),"ITEM"=c(13048, 13057, 13082, 13048, 13057, 13145, 13166, 13229, 13057, 13048),"DATE_SALE"=as.Date(c("1/1/2014","1/1/2014","1/2/2014","1/2/2014","1/2/2014","1/2/2014","1/3/2014","1/3/2014","1/3/2014","1/4/2014"),"%m/%d/%Y"),"QNT_SALE"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

df_sales

   STORE  ITEM  DATE_SALE QNT_SALE
1   1001 13048 2014-01-01        1
2   1001 13057 2014-01-01        1
3   1001 13082 2014-01-02        1
4   1001 13048 2014-01-02        1
5   1001 13057 2014-01-02        1
6   1002 13145 2014-01-02        1
7   1002 13166 2014-01-03        1
8   1002 13229 2014-01-03        1
9   1002 13057 2014-01-03        1
10  1002 13048 2014-01-04        1

df_supply <- data.frame("STORE"=c(1001,1002,1001,1001,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002,1002),"ITEM"=c(13048,13229,13057,13082,13145,13166,13229,13057,13048,13048),"DATE_SUPPLY"=as.Date(c("1/31/2013","1/31/2013","1/31/2013","1/1/2014","1/2/2014","1/2/2014","1/2/2014","1/2/2014","1/3/2014","2/1/2014"),"%m/%d/%Y"),"QNT_SUPPLY"=c(2,1,2,1,1,1,2,3,1,2))
df_supply
   STORE  ITEM DATE_SUPPLY CUM_QNT_SUPPLY
1   1001 13048 2013-01-31          2
2   1002 13229 2013-01-31          1
3   1001 13057 2013-01-31          2
4   1001 13082 2014-01-01          1
5   1002 13145 2014-01-02          1
6   1002 13166 2014-01-02          1
7   1002 13229 2014-01-02          2
8   1002 13057 2014-01-02          3
9   1002 13048 2014-01-03          1
10  1002 13048 2014-02-01          2



Output Required:
Sales Vs Supply
   STORE  ITEM  DATE_SALE QNT_SALE  DATE_SUPPLY QNT_SUPPLY
1   1001 13048 2014-01-01        1  2013-01-31          2
2   1001 13057 2014-01-01        1  2013-01-31          2
3   1001 13082 2014-01-02        1  2014-01-01          1
4   1001 13048 2014-01-02        1  2013-01-31          2
5   1001 13057 2014-01-02        1  2013-01-31          2
6   1002 13145 2014-01-03        1  2014-01-02          1
7   1002 13166 2014-01-03        1  2014-01-02          1
8   1002 13229 2014-01-03        1  2014-01-02          2
9   1002 13057 2014-01-03        1  2014-01-02          3
10  1002 13048 2014-01-04        1  2014-01-03          1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something you can try, using `merge` and relevant ordering (`order`):

```
# order the data.frames
df_sales <- df_sales[order(-df_sales$STORE, -df_sales$ITEM, df_sales$DATE_SALE, decreasing=T), ]
df_supply <- df_supply[order(-df_supply$STORE, -df_supply$ITEM, df_supply$DATE_SUPPLY, decreasing=T), ]

# merge the data.frames
res <- merge(df_sales, df_supply, by=c("STORE","ITEM"), all=T)

# keep only records with DATE_SUPPLY anterior to DATE_SALE
res <- res[with(res, DATE_SUPPLY <= DATE_SALE), ]

# remove duplicates (based on STORE, ITEM and DATE_SALE)
res <- res[!duplicated(res[, 1:3]), ]

res
   # STORE  ITEM  DATE_SALE QNT_SALE DATE_SUPPLY QNT_SUPPLY
# 1   1001 13048 2014-01-02        1  2013-01-31          2
# 2   1001 13048 2014-01-01        1  2013-01-31          2
# 3   1001 13057 2014-01-02        1  2013-01-31          2
# 4   1001 13057 2014-01-01        1  2013-01-31          2
# 5   1001 13082 2014-01-02        1  2014-01-01          1
# 7   1002 13048 2014-01-04        1  2014-01-03          1
# 8   1002 13057 2014-01-03        1  2014-01-02          3
# 9   1002 13145 2014-01-02        1  2014-01-02          1
# 10  1002 13166 2014-01-03        1  2014-01-02          1
# 11  1002 13229 2014-01-03        1  2014-01-02          2
```

Comment: I am not sure how this will perform with a different dataset where there are non-matching dates, but for this example, it works

Comment: that's why the examples must be representative ;-)

Comment: @akrun this is really a rolling join question, especially while been tagged with `data.table` but my attempt to solve it was unsuccessful for some reason. Did you try it?

Comment: @DavidArenburg No, I didn't try it.

Comment: I wrote a solution but can't make it populate all the fields for some reason.

Comment: @CathG, this won't work if there is next supply date is greater than the sales, suppose if i've sale_date = 2014-01-03 for product_id= 13048 and store_id = 1002, i.e., the last output row but it has another supply in next month 2014-02-01. According to order by clause this date will be picked which is not right because I need the just recent supply_date before or on the same day of sales.

Comment: @CathG, edited code is not resulting the same number of sales record. I need number of record in output should be equal to number of records in sales. i.e., df_sales = 10

Comment: @CathG: for store 1001, item 13057 Sale has been made on 2014-01-01 and 2014-01-02 while supply was only on 2013-01-31. So for both the sale row there should be date_supply as 2013-01-31.
The concept is sale has to be made on just previous supply. 
DATE_SUPPLY < DATE_SALE, where as DATE_SUPPLY is just previous supply date of corresponding item.

Comment: i.e., "2013" not "2014", 3   1001 13057 2013-01-31          2

Comment: This is nice (+1), but just not as efficient as we materialise the entire merge only to subset later.

Comment: @Arun, thanks and I am totally aware this can be optimized ;-) I'm glad to see a `data.table` solution and can't wait to "study" it :-)

Answer (score 5):

Using *rolling joins* from `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df_supply), STORE, ITEM, DATE_SUPPLY)
idx = df_supply[df_sales, roll=Inf, which=TRUE]
cbind(df_sales, df_supply[idx, 3:4])
#    STORE  ITEM  DATE_SALE QNT_SALE DATE_SUPPLY QNT_SUPPLY
# 1   1001 13048 2014-01-01        1  2013-01-31          2
# 2   1001 13057 2014-01-01        1  2013-01-31          2
# 3   1001 13082 2014-01-02        1  2014-01-01          1
# 4   1001 13048 2014-01-02        1  2013-01-31          2
# 5   1001 13057 2014-01-02        1  2013-01-31          2
# 6   1002 13145 2014-01-02        1  2014-01-02          1
# 7   1002 13166 2014-01-03        1  2014-01-02          1
# 8   1002 13229 2014-01-03        1  2014-01-02          2
# 9   1002 13057 2014-01-03        1  2014-01-02          3
# 10  1002 13048 2014-01-04        1  2014-01-03          1
```

`cbind` returns an entirely new object. If instead you'd like to add the new columns *by reference* to `df_sales` use `:=` instead. There are numerous examples of using it here on SO and also explained under the [new HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: idx = df_supply[df_sales, roll=Inf, which=TRUE], this line is throwing error, as actual dataset has ITEM as factor. Tried to convert STORE also a factor as actual ITEM id has factor value so ITEM can't be treated as numeric. I'm facing below error:

Error in bmerge(i <- shallow(i), x, leftcols, rightcols, io <- haskey(i),  : 
  x.'STORE_ID' is a factor column being joined to i.'Row' which is type 'integer'. Factor columns must join to factor or character columns.